# How to change a value in a specific row in sql?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a table with different columns among which are `tasks` and `username`.

I want to change the value of `tasks` for a specific `username` and I am trying to use `UPDATE` but it removes all the previous data:

```
c.execute('UPDATE users SET tasks = "' + x + '" WHERE username = "' + username + '"')
```

Like this the old data gets removed and tasks is set to `x` but what I want is to add `x` to `tasks`. How do I do that instead?

Comment: I don't think this problem is caused by `tkinter`. If so, please remove the `tkinter` tag

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate to `tasks` rather than overwriting it.

```
c.execute('UPDATE users SET tasks = tasks || "," || ? WHERE username = ?', (x, username))
```

Note that it's poor database design to put comma-delimited lists in table columns. You should have another table `user_tasks` with a row for each user+task combination.

Comment: oops, i think this might be my fault bc i didnt mention i was using sqlite3 but it says:
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: CONCAT

Comment: I did see that it was sqlite, but forgot that it doesn't have CONCAT.

Comment: Well sorry for disturbing you again, but I get the error : ```sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: x```. It would make sense, since I meant x to be a variable. I am using ! as a delimiter btw., not commas.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been another placeholder `?` to get the value of the `x` parameter.